# create an index of all API calls with enunciate

Tags: enunciate

I develop a not-so-RESTful API using Jersey and Jackson. All the API calls are annotated with `@Path`, `@GET`/`@POST`, `@Produces` and `@Consumes`. I managed to generate a nice API documentation using **enunciate**.

The question is:

**Is it possible to tell enunciate to create a single HTML page that would contain an index with all the API calls?**

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to try your own custom freemarker transform to output your own index page. See [Applying a Custom Skin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Applying+a+Custom+Skin+to+Enunciate%27s+Documentation) for more information.

You could also try using Enunciate's new Swagger integration. [Swagger UI](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui) is kind of an index...